# como saber cuantas instancias de una clase tengo en el codigo?

Tags: javascript

como hago para saber cuantas instancias de una clase tengo en un codigo.

por ejemplo si tengo que buscar todos los alumnos que cursan matematica, que formas de hacerlo tengo? gracisa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen Día, necesitas agregar el código como texto, no como imagen, además es de que proporciones que haz intentado y que esperas recibir. y te sugiero que revises el apartado  te sugiero que revises el apartado [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask);

Comment: pues guardarias todos esos alumnos en una lista, y luego recorrerias la lista y por cada alumno que pertenezca a lo que estas buscando, sumarias uno....

Comment: tengo forma de recorrer como si fuese un for las instancias creadas?

por ejemplo si quiero recorrer todas las instancias Alumnos para saber que instancia se inicio con el nombre X?

Comment: no, tendrías que meter cada item de tu instancia que generas a un array y entonces si recorrerlo, con un foreach o un  for of,